# PnP PowerShell - update SharePoint list fields from existing SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, pnp-powershell

We need to fetch data from one SharePoint list and then update those fields data into another SharePoint list using PnP PowerShell. Can anyone please guide or share PnP script for us? Thanks in advance.

Note: We are using **SharePoint Online**

Answer (score 0):

```
$Username='user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
$Password = '************'

#region Credentials
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass)
#endregion Credentials

#connect to hubsite
Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SitrName' -Credentials $PSCredentials
$OlistItems = Get-PnPListItem -List 'OldList'
foreach($item in $OlistItems) {
        #Create object
  $itemVal = @{
    'Title' = $item['Title']
  }
  Add-PnPListItem -List 'NewList' -Values $itemVal -ContentType "Item"
}
```